# Need help in opening of binary files

Tags: binary-analysis, game

## Need help with unreadable Far Cry 6 binary format (.spx)

Hi everyone, name is Adi :-).

For the past few weeks I've been searching for a solution to a problem that the [Far Cry Modding Community](https://discord.gg/farcry-modding-846424998888734731) with me among them, is struggling to solve for quite some time with no success.

We have those unknown binary files with `.spx` extension that [FCB Converter](https://downloads.fcmodding.com/others/fcbconverter/) can only recognize a part of and convert it to `.xml`, but there is another part that we can't figure out, that FCB Converter produces together with the `.xml` file as `.phx` (gibberish file) from *Far Cry 6* PC game that we can't read nor edit. The files are associated with the Ubisoft in-house UI engine Phoenix of the game in `installpkg_unpacked\ui\zeta\phoenix`.

We need to open and be able to read the entire SPX files and convert them to an openable format in order to figure out the mechanism of the Phoenix UI engine and find a way to add a new language char set into the game so that the game can support more languages.

The main interest now is to add the Hebrew language which is in high demand due to the new FC6 hebrew translation project that is under taken today along with the possibility of back-and-forth `.spx` file convertion to/from a readable file format.

### Location of the .spx files

[image: Location of the .spx files]

### Previous work

#### Attempt 1

At first, after converting the `.oasis.bin` files from `common_unpacked\languages\english` to XML using FCB Converter, we simply tried to translate the `converted_xml` strings in a XML editor and repack everything. Hence the converted XML is encoded in UTF-8 we figured the approach would work (results below).

Steps we took:

1. Extract the english subtitles files that are in `common_unpacked\languages\english` as XML files using FCB Converter.
2. Edit the english strings inside the `converted.xml` files to Hebrew language (UTF-8).
3. Convert the XMLs back to `.oasiss.bin`.
4. Replace the files with the one in `common_unpacked\languages\english`
5. Repack the `common_unpacked` folder to `common.dat` and `common.fat` files using FCB converter.
6. Replace the new `common.dat` and the new `common.fat` files with the original ones in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Far Cry 6\data_final\pc`
7. Launch the game.

The strings we edited appeared as question marks inside the game (`?????????????????`).

The process is illustrated below.

[image]

[image]

[image: extracting the language xml files]

#### Attempt 2

---

We tried to replace `.ttf` and `.otf` fonts located in `common_unpacked\ui\common\fonts\src` with Hebrew fonts. We just renamed the Hebrew font and replaced it with the original one.

Steps we took:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Far Cry 6\data_final\pc`.
2. Extract `Common.fat` and `Common.dat` using FCB Converter.
3. Go to the `common_unpacked\ui\common\fonts\src`.
4. Change the fonts to Hebrew with the same names and extensions.

Same result unfortunately - the strings we edited appeared as question marks inside of the game.

### Conclusion

Far Cry 6 uses a special UI engine called Phoenix that uses its own settings to determine the language character set to be used with a specific language. So each language installed in the game has its own charset setting, at least this is what we assume is happening here. No doubt we need more understanding of the `.spx` files and you here are the best source we can find to deal with binary files like these ones. Any help would be greatly appreciated by the entire Far Cry modding community. Thanks to everyone.

The SPX files are very small. **[Click here](https://easyupload.io/rvjq71)** to download all of them with their original subfolders added to a zip archive.